# Why the sequence of pair of differential groups is exact?

Tags: homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

An abelian group $A$ with a homomorphism $d: A \longrightarrow A$ is called *differential group* if $d^2 = 0$.

Let $(A, d)$ be a differential group, $B \leq A$, $d: B \longrightarrow B$.
Then $A, B, \frac{A}{B}$ are differential groups, I'll use the same $d$ for the differentials.

We may take a look on the short exact sequence:

$0 \to B \stackrel{i}{\to} A \stackrel{j}{\to} \frac{A}{B} \to 0$.

Now to the point of my question, I read that taking the homology of this exact sequence gives us an exact sequnce which is called the *homology exat sequnce of pair of differential groups*:

$... \stackrel{j_\star}{\to} H(\frac{A}{B}, d) \stackrel{\partial}{\to} H(B, d) \stackrel{i_\star}{\to} H(A, d) \stackrel{j_\star}{\to} H(\frac{A}{B}, d) \stackrel{\partial}{\to} H(B, d) \stackrel{i_\star}{\to} ...$.

I am cheking the exatness. I cheked the exactness in $H(A, d), H(B, d)$ but I  get nothing good in the $H(\frac{A}{B}, d)$. Can you help me with that?

Ivo Terek gave the answer in the comments

Comment: I think that the conftruction of $\partial$ is something well-known but if not I can write it in the post

Comment: A differential group $(A,d)$ is the same thing as a constant complex $(A^\bullet, d^\bullet)$ with $$\cdots \to A \to A \to A \to \cdots$$and all arrows being $d$. So the short exact sequence you have can be thought of as a short exact sequence of complexes. And a short exact sequence of complexes induces a long exact sequence in homology: any book in algebraic topology or homological algebra will have the proof (look it up on Hatcher, Rotman, Weibel, or whatever book comes to your mind). You can just run their proof for your particular constant complexes.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thank you! I've seen that proofs, but I didn't figure out how to connect them with a differential group

Comment: Been there, done that. But instead of differential groups, I was playing with differential vector spaces (Chapter 6 of Linear Algebra by Werner Greub). I got stuck in something similar until someone pointed out to me that it was just a constant complex. I never forgot it. I guess it was time to pass the tip forward. :-)